# light action bar support library: why it doesn t work?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm using the support v7 library and in my style in valus-v11 i set

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

The problem is that the ActionBar is Dark and i would like Light. Also the dialogs are Dark and i would like light. How can i fix?

Here is written https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

"Theme.AppCompat.Light for the "light" theme." but doen't work

Comment: if its api level 11 why do you need SupportLibrary ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this link

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html

Customize according to what you want. See the parent style `@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar`

```
<style name="Theme.Styled" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" 
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_custom_solid_styled</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked"
        >@drawable/ab_custom_stacked_solid_styled</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit"
        >@drawable/ab_custom_bottom_solid_styled</item>
</style>
```